# Laravel class seeder not found when artisan --seed

Tags: laravel

I manually added CategoriesSeeder.php like this in folder database/seeds:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Category;

class CategoriesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = 'kategoria1';
        $category->save();

        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = 'kategoria2';
        $category->save();

        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = 'kategoria3';
        $category->save();
    }
}
```

ad I mentioned about it in my DatabaseSeeder.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(CategoriesSeeder::class);

    }
}
```

after I type

```
 λ php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

I got response:

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class CategoriesSeeder does not exist
```

What I'm doing wrong? I knot that I should add command

```
λ php artisan make:seeder CategoriesSeeder
```

but how to do it manually?

Comment: Run `composer du` and try again

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin thank you!

Comment: Why on thea artisan commands starts with a greek lamda (*λ*)?